# How to update page data, without refreshing page, using jQuery

Tags: jquery

I need to make  modifications to a website that forces me to update data in the page without refreshing its content. The system should change so when a visitor enters a part number, the price for a single unit along with the discount for quantities is displayed.
When the visitor chooses a quantity that entitles the visitor for a discount a new price together with corresponding discount band is displayed.
The system that we have works now fine but it includes several stages and would not let the user select the quantity at the initial search stage.
I need to use jquery to connect to database  and fetch the correct price and discount band for the quantity chosen.
here is the code that needs changing.

```
 <body >


<table  border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" align="center">
<tr> 
<td  align="center">

 <?php
 include ("../includes/java_update.php");
?>
<table   width="100%" >

                        <?php
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
    {
        // Increment the total cost of all items
        ?>
<tr class="inside1">
                          <td colspan="8"><hr size="1" >                                </td>
                        <tr id="inside">
                             <td><input  type="text" name="<?php echo $row["part_number"];?>"    value="<?php echo $row["qty"];?>" id="t"  onBlur="UpdateQty2(this.name,this.value)"  size="3" >                              </td>
                          <td><input name="button" type="button"value="Update" class="button"></td>
                              <td class="disc" width="12%" height="25"><?php echo    $row["part_number"]; ?> </td>
                              <td class="discleft" width="39%" height="25">
 <?php 



                            echo $row["disc"]; ?>                              </td>
                          <td id="price" width="6%" height="25">&pound;
                              <?php 

                            for($in =1 ; $in <= 8; $in++)
                            {
                            $bb=$row["price_break".($in)];

                            $halves =explode("-",$bb);
                            $firstnumber=$halves[0];
                            $secondnumber=$halves[1];




                        If ($row["qty"] >= $firstnumber && $row["qty"] <= $secondnumber)

                        {
                        echo number_format($row[("price_each".$in)], 2, ".", ",");


                    tprice ($row["part_number"],$row[("price_each".$in)],$row[("qty")]);
                    //echo"part_number is ".$row["part_number"];
                    //echo "<br>";
                    //echo"price_each is ".$row[("price_each".$in)];


                        $which=$in;

                        $totalCost += ($row["qty"] * $row[("price_each".$which)] );
                        }


                            }



                                ?>                            </td>
                           <td align="center"  class="in_stock">

                          </td>
                          <td width="9%" height="25" class="pblist" ><select name="pb" >
                              <?php


                        $c=$row["price_each1"];//  price for single item


                            for($i = 1; $i <= 8; $i++)
                            {


                            $b=$row["price_each".$i];


                            if ($b !=0.00)
                                {

                                $d=(($c-$b)/$c)*100;



                            $complete=$row[("price_break".$i)]. " ," .round($d)."%";    
                    echo "<option ";


                            if ($i == $which)
                                    {
                                        echo " SELECTED ";
                                    }
                            echo ">". $complete ."</option>";       



                            }
                            }


                            ?>
                          </select>                              </td>
                          <td id="removeit"><a id="removeit" href="cart_wp.php?    action=remove_item&id=<?php echo $row["part_number"]; ?>">Remove</a> </td>
                        </tr>

<script type="text/javascript">

function UpdateQty2(s,m)
            {
        var part_number=s;




        if (isNaN (m)) {
    // Not A Number
   alert('Please enter a valid no.') ;
 } else {


        var newQty=m;


        document.location.href = 'cart_wp.php?action=update_item&id='+part_number+'&qty='+newQty;
        }


    }
```

Comment: indent & re-format your code first, please

Answer (score 2):

[$.post()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/) documentation

```
$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: url,
  data: data,
  success: success,
  dataType: dataType
});
```